# What is the best way to compare 2 tables in php?

Tags: php

I've got 2 CSV files like

```
id;date;name
```

and

```
id;date
```

The semi-colon `;` is a separator

What is the best and the most performance way to find count of elements which are in the 1st table and not in the 2nd?

I now only one method is foreach. But it takes O(n1*n2) time.

Comment: Read each file into a database table and query for difference.

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/7864423/

Answer (score 4):

Put all ids from each file into arrays `$first` and `$second`, then do

```
$onlyInFirst = array_diff($first, $second);
```

There are other sister functions to [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) that allow you to determine which items exist in both arrays, or allow you to compute the difference if you already have the data into arrays and it's structured somewhat differently.

Comment: what if I want to compare only id, not another fields?

Comment: @Anton2012: That's why I suggested to put only the ids into the arrays.